# Change the 'jenkins' default USER (user_name) on mac

Tags: jenkins

I just installed Jenkins on our mac server.
However, looking at the configuration page, it set user.name=jenkins and USER=jenkins
How do I change the 'jenkins' default USER (user_name) on the mac server to something else?

Any help is really appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends on how did you install Jenkins, but I will assume you used the official Jenkins installer for Mac.

As you can see from [the launch daemon config file](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/osx/launchd_conf_jenkins/org.jenkins-ci.plist), the username is hard-coded. You will have to change the file, which is installed into your system at `/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist`

First, stop Jenkins by running `launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist`

Change the UserName from "jenkins" to the user you want to use to run Jenkins.

You will need to also change JENKINS_HOME to point to a directory where your preferred user has write permission. (Or change `/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home` to be owned by your preferred user.)

Then start Jenkins by running `launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist`

The next time you upgrade using the Mac installer, your changes will be overwritten, so you will have to do it all over again. It might be safer to stop using the Mac installer and just download the new `jenkins.war` file  and replace it manually.

Comment: Thanks! In my case I had to also change ownership of /var/log/jenkins to the user I wanted to run Jenkins.

Answer (score -1):

Better to create new user, it will have all the setup those are configured with old user.

**Manage Jenkins > Manage Users > Create User > Provide User Name, Password, Email & all required details**

Now login with the new created user name > it will have all the configuration, those were there with old user