# git fetch --tags --progress times out in Jenkins, works fine on command line

Tags: git, macos, jenkins

I've configured Jenkins to poll a Git repository, I'm using https not ssh. The following URL is configured, and I use a username and password.

```
https://myusername@stash.ourdomain.com:8443/scm/ourrepo/ourrepo-ios.git
```

When I run the build, it stalls for 10 minutes and times out. When I copy the line where it times out and paste it to command line on the same machine as Jenkins runs (a macOS server), it works:

```
git fetch --tags --progress https://myusername@stash.ourdomain.com:8443/scm/ourrepo/ourrepo-ios.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Why is it stuck for 10 minutes? I tried to use wrong credentials and that'll fail in a second. It's not a huge repo.

---

The log:

```
Started by user Jenkins Admin
Building in workspace /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Build and test new commits on develop
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://myusername@stash.ourdomain.com:8443/scm/ourrepo/ourrepo-ios.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://myusername@stash.ourdomain.com:8443/scm/ourrepo/ourrepo-ios.git
> git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --progress https://myusername@stash.ourdomain.com:8443/scm/ourrepo/ourrepo-ios.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from https://myusername@stash.ourdomain.com:8443/scm/ourrepo/ourrepo-ios.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:803)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1063)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1094)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:495)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1278)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:604)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1728)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress https://myusername@stash.ourdomain.com:8443/scm/ourrepo/ourrepo-ios.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 143:stdout: 
stderr: 
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1745)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1489)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:64)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:315)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:801)
    ... 11 more
ERROR: null
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Do the git polling logs show anything useful?

Comment: Can you attach Jenkins `build's console output` to you original post?

Comment: I've just added it

Comment: When you ran the command in the console, did you run it in the same repository and as the same user as your jenkins job?

Comment: Same repo, same git user

Comment: When you ran the command in console, under which OS user you are? `jenkins`?

Comment: I added Jenkins as a user to macOS and logged in as Jenkins. Ran the same job again. It worked. If either of you Ivan or @HaldeanBrown wants to collect the glory please answer, I'm tired of answering my own questions here ;) Found the solution on http://www.cimgf.com/2015/05/26/setting-up-jenkins-ci-on-a-mac-2/ "Setting up the Jenkins user"

Comment: @Ivan was closer to the right answer, he can have it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check if user `jenkins` exists on your OS and it has right permissions.

How to set up `jenkins` user on Mac OS X:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/24129589/5104202
- https://medium.com/@ved.pandey/setting-up-jenkins-on-mac-osx-50d8fe16df9f

**EDIT**

Please try this (I didn't test it):

- Make the Jenkins user an admin: `sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a jenkins -t user admin`
- Add the Jenkins user to the developer group: `sudo dscl . append /Groups/_developer GroupMembership jenkins`
- Make the Jenkins user automatically login when the computer is restarted

Comment: If Jenkins slave on your windows is running as a service under user "local service", you can change it to another 'real' user. So you can login with this user to Windows and check any command (i.e. "git clone") and any permission

Comment: Answer is no longer helpful.  Dead link.